# How can I hide desktop icon names in Unity desktop, Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: unity, icons

Is it possible to hide the text under the desktop icons? I'd like to have them fit into the background and the text is a bit ugly.
setting the text to blanks or spaces would make them not work because they are references to app launchers.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity launcher if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, Google search reveals nothing. I might have to install a VM, because believe it or not I don't have an ubuntu machine 

Comment: You earned my upvote though. Since a google search reveals ~nothing, any answers to this question would be a great resource to anyone in the future

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Looks like you got a good answer!  Don't [forget to accept](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Install package dconf-tools

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Open dconf-editor

```
dconf-editor
```

under `/org/gnome/nautilus/desktop` change the `"font"` key to `"Ubuntu 0"`

[image]

Command-line alternative to this same approach which doesn't require `dconf-editor` installation is the following command (note the quoting):

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/desktop/font '"Ubuntu 0"'
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Good one!  Upvoted!

Comment: Thank you Fabby. And thanks Serg for the image display correction.